# Flushing rewrite rules enables to see an article, but I didnt change anything

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I know this wont be so precizely written, but I cant describe it any better.
Im in admin, and I pressed the save button on "permalinks option".

I have an article: `www.example.com/video/title` which then will lead to the main page (just showing, not redirected!).

But as soon as I make this in `init` action: `$_GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->flush_rules(true);` it starts working immediatly!

But I didnt change anything on rewrite rules! So how or when could it be modified?

Comment: Note that you shouldn't need to flush rewrite rules on every page load, it's enough to just go to the permalinks settings page and save to flush rewrite rules. Was this article the first post in a new custom post type?

Comment: nope, it wasn't